# How to use vue-moment in vuex

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, vuex

Im using this [vue-moment](https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment#readme) library without any problem. But I can't use it in Vuex.

I tried:

```
this.$moment()
this.moment()
---
import vue from 'vue'
vue.moment()
---
import vueMoment from 'vue-moment'
vueMoment.moment()
```

and always get an error.

Comment: Maybe you can share the error ?

Comment: "Cannot read property '$moment' of undefined" or "Uncaught TypeError: vue_moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function"

Comment: I think you need to share more details. Like your modules initializations in Vue. Did you register Vuex & vue-moment modules ?

Comment: Ok, question is: How to use vue-moment library in Vuex. That's it. Forgot about errors

Comment: "in Vuex" means nothing. Vuex is a vue module to manage state, vue moment is a module to wrap momentjs. This is two different things. If you just want to use vue-moment with Vue, simply use Vue.use(require('vue-moment')) in your configuration and then use moment as a data-filter like the doc says...

Comment: Ok, another way to ask: How to use vue-moment in a .js file?

Comment: Are you really using vue.js ? If you include vue-moment with Vue you have access to it with this.moment() in your Vue components. Instead if you just want to use the features of moment, just use momentjs library and not vue-moment.

Comment: YES, Im using vue, and Im able to use vue-moment like this.$moment() in my vue components. I know my english is not my native languaje but I think the question is very clear: Use vue-moment libray in any .js file (like store). I know I can install momentjs and use it. But Im avoiding have 2 BIG librearies like vue-moment and moment. That's is Why my question.

Answer (score 4):

When using vue-moment in a vuex module you can't use `this.$moment` but you can use it like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
...
Vue.moment(someTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use it as a plugin `Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));` before starting the instance of the vue instance

secondly you can use it like this as an example`Vue.moment()`.. just replicated and it worked

this is how the start of my file looks like

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));

export default new Vuex.Store({
//the rest of the state.js file
})
```